# Compaq Presario SR1103WM POSTS, but refuses to boot any OS off any medium, no matter what

Tags: boot, windows-xp, freeze, troubleshooting, repair

I've tried booting off anything and everything, CD, USB, HDD (Windows 98 SE Bootdisk off CD (only one that worked), GParted Live 1.4.0 off CD/USB, Windows XP Home/Pro off HDD), and I haven't got a single one to work (except win98 se bootdisk). Attempting to boot the OEM Windows XP Home installation just turned the screen black right on the boot splash screen, fans went to the lowest setting, screen black, computer completely unresponsive. Attempting to boot a fresh installation of Windows XP Pro SP3 yielded the same results. I could boot into the XP recovery console, but not much I could do there so I just reinstalled. Trying to boot GParted off a CD yielded the same results that XP did, off USB either same results as the CD or I would get something along the lines of "kernel panic" or "end kernel panic" and usually complain about something with the BIOS.

To sum it up, I've tried:

Re-seating the RAM

Testing the RAM

New IDE cables

Different power supplies

Attempting to boot off several different mediums of several different contents

Reinstalling Windows XP

Various different BIOS settings

Resetting the CMOS several times

Removing all add-in cards (a PCI dial-up modem)

More about the "unresponsive state":

When attempting to boot ANYTHING off ANYTHING, usually on the splash screen or right in the middle of boot (before any drivers are loaded, it's not a driver issue), the screen immediately goes black, and all the fans rev down and blow out icy cool air, even the PSU cools down a bit. The power button has to be held down to restart it and even then the power light stays on for some reason. The disc drive doesn't open, but the hard drive keeps spinning and still sounds like its accessing something.
I have tried absolutely everything to prevent this state or keep it out of it for even a little bit longer, and nothing.

I've tried two power supplies, the original one is definitely still good, top shape and not showing any signs of failing. The CMOS battery was still fine, it kept all the settings and the exact time and date, I reset the CMOS several times to no avail. I've re-seated the RAM, disabled quick boot and let the RAM be tested during POST, I've tested both sticks with memtest86 and they never yielded errors. The hard drive/disc drive I felt was a little bit twitchy, and the hard drive kept spinning and clicking even after I got the infamous black screen with GParted/XP, but I dont think its the cause of the issue as they are detected just fine and grub still loads off CD and XP recovery console/NTLDR still loads off the hard drive. I grabbed a light and inspected all the capacitors, and while they don't appear in *top* shape, they all appear to be still working though I have double checked, since this computer was made in the middle of the capacitor armageddon.

There's lots of dust, which I blow off when I find it anywhere substantial. Other than the dust and the old (but not broken) capacitors the motherboard and its components are in good enough shape.

I. Have. Tried. EVERYTHING.

If you've ever experienced a similar issue with this PC or a PC like it, or you know what the cause and fix might be, please tell me, it's had me dumbfounded for 2 days now.

Comment: How much memory do you have in your notebook. I've found this: http://www.compaqcomputermemory.com/compaq-computer/CompaqPresarioSR1103WMB.html It says 1GB is the maximum acceptable RAM. In addition if you were able to start the memtest I think your computer works. The only thing that is not involved during memtest is HDD. The construction is very old so I would try with an old OS like this: https://winworldpc.com/product/red-hat-linux/50

Comment: Ahh sorry I linked the notebook instead of the PC: https://www.ebay.com/itm/384750585523 But I would answer still the same. Try to boot up with an older OS.

Comment: Well the tower shipped with Windows XP Home, and when XP was in that state I reinstalled with XP Pro SP3, and the GParted live cd I believe contains an old enough version of Debian for this PC. Maybe the cooler is filled with dust, this is an ancient celeron on a fairly old, unmaintained cooler so I'll try cleaning out the dust. I'll also try Red Hat 5 on a new, clean drive.

Comment: Red Hat 5 might actually (somewhat) solve this problem, after all it loaded *a* OS, DOS with CD and FAT32 support off a Windows 98 Bootdisk, on a CD! That's basically the same thing as DOS off my hard drive, so i'll try getting DOS working then Red Hat 5, then see if I can get NT 4.0 or atleast Windows 98 SE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot up with an older OS from the era when the PC was released.